# Change ABP.io Lepton X Lite brand on MVC [5.3.4]

Tags: abp

Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Theme.LeptonXLite theme to have a metronic lite site on my ABP.io MVC app, but I'm not able to change the Brand.
I've followed [this guide](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/AspNetCore/Branding) on changing it on ABP but it doesn't seems to apply.

Any one was able to change it?
Thanks

Comment: Could you have look at it here, please?
(https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/6.0/Themes/LeptonXLite/AspNetCore)

Comment: I saw it and also recreated those folders inside my .Web application, but with no luck
How to override the Page Alerts Component in LeptonX Lite Mvc
The page alerts component page (.cshtml file) is defined in the Themes/LeptonXLite/Components/PageAlerts/Default.cshtml file and you can override it by creating a file with the same name and under the same folder.

The page alerts component (C#) is defined in the Themes/LeptonXLite/Components/PageAlerts/PageAlertsViewComponent.cs file and you can override it by creating a file with the same name and under the same folder.